# How to change the tables' fontsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing a table with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.table`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html) like this:

```
    sub_axes.table(cellText=table_vals,
          colWidths = [0.15, 0.25],
          rowLabels=row_labels,
          loc='right')
```

I'd like to change the fontsize of table's content, and found there is a `fontsize` property.

So it becomes:

```
    sub_axes.table(cellText=table_vals,
          colWidths = [0.15, 0.25],
          rowLabels=row_labels,
          fontsize=12,
          loc='right')
```

But when I execute the code, I got an error:

```
TypeError: table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'
```

Is this property deprecated? And how can I change the fontsize of table with pyplot?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think the documentation is either hinting at a parameter-to-be (notice `fontsize` is not a link like the other parameters) or perhaps is a bit misleading at the moment. There is no `fontsize` parameter.

Digging through [the source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/table.py#L371), I found the `Table.set_fontsize` method:

```
table = sub_axes.table(cellText=table_vals,
                       colWidths = [0.15, 0.25],
                       rowLabels=row_labels,
                       loc='right')
table.set_fontsize(14)
table.scale(1.5, 1.5)  # may help
```

---

Here is an example with a grossly exaggerated fontsize just to show the effect.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8531491/190597 (Andrey Sobolev)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]    
col_labels = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
row_labels = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']
table_vals = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
                      colWidths=[0.1] * 3,
                      rowLabels=row_labels,
                      colLabels=col_labels,
                      loc='center right')
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(24)
the_table.scale(2, 2)

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For this to work, I had to add `the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)` before set new font size

Comment: the_table.set_fontsize was not working in my code, but a recreation did work.  This comment and suggestion table.auto_set_font_size(False) fixed it.  The question is, why did it need to be done in one script but not another?  It was not set to true anywhere, and true does not appear to be the default.  To try to troubleshoot I found in matplotlib.table the method get_fontsize().  But it doesn't work -- says Table object has no attribute 'get_fontsize'.

Answer (score 43):

Set the `auto_set_font_size` to `False`, then `set_fontsize(24)`

```
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(24)
```

Comment: Is there any way to adjust fontsize in `pylab.rcParams` perhaps?

Comment: I like this line: auto_set_font_size