# Matplotlib Table's Font Size

Tags: python, matplotlib

Working with Matplotlib in Python (2.7.9). I have to plot a table in a subplot (in this case subplot name is tab) but I can't seem to find a way to change the font size of the table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TToAa.jpg - bottom left). Antman is happy about the results, I am not.
This is the code I've been using.

EDIT: Added full code

```
def stat_chart(self):

DN      = self.diff
ij      = self.ij_list
mcont   = self.mcont
ocont   = self.ocont
ucont   = self.ucont
dist    = self.widths
clon    = '%1.2f' %self.mclon
clat    = '%1.2f' %self.mclat
clonlat = "{0}/{1}".format(clon,clat)
area    = self.area
perim   = self.perimeter
mdist   = np.array(self.widths)
mdist   = mdist[:,0]*10
mdist   = np.mean(mdist)
pstat   = self.polygon_status
if pstat == 1:
  status = "Overestimation"
else:
  status = "Underestimation"

# Setting up the plot (2x2) and subplots
fig   = plt.figure()
gs    = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2,width_ratios=[2,1],height_ratios=[4,1])
main  = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
polyf = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
tab   = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
leg   = plt.subplot(gs[1,1])
tab.set_xticks([])
leg.set_xticks([])
tab.set_yticks([])
leg.set_yticks([])
tab.set_frame_on(False)
leg.set_frame_on(False)

# Main image on the top left
main.imshow(DN[::-1],cmap='winter')
x1,x2,y1,y2 = np.min(ij[:,1])-15,np.max(ij[:,1])+15,np.min(ij[:,0])-15,np.max(ij[:,0])+15
main.axvspan(x1,x2,ymin=1-((y1-320)/float(len(DN)-320)),ymax=1-((y2-320)/float(len(DN)-320)),color='red',alpha=0.3)
main.axis([0,760,0,800])

# Polygon image on the top right
polyf.imshow(DN,cmap='winter')
polyf.axis([x1,x2,y2,y1])
polyf.plot(mcont[:,1],mcont[:,0],'ro',markersize=4)
polyf.plot(ocont[:,1],ocont[:,0],'yo',markersize=4)
polyf.plot(ucont[:,1],ucont[:,0],'go',markersize=4)
for n,en in enumerate(dist):
  polyf.plot([en[2],en[4]],[en[1],en[3]],color='grey',alpha=0.3)

# Legend on the bottom right
mc = mlines.Line2D([],[],color='red',marker='o')
oc = mlines.Line2D([],[],color='yellow',marker='o')
uc = mlines.Line2D([],[],color='green',marker='o')
ed = mlines.Line2D([],[],color='black',alpha=0.5)
pos_p = mpatches.Patch(color='lightgreen')
neg_p = mpatches.Patch(color='royalblue')
leg.legend([mc,oc,uc,ed,pos_p,neg_p],("Model Cont.","Osisaf Cont.","Unknown Cont.","Dist. Mdl to Osi", \
  'Model Overestimate','Model Underestimate'),loc='center')

# Statistics table on the bottom left
stats = [[clonlat+' degrees' ,'%1.4E km^2' %area,'%1.4E km' %perim,'%1.4f km' %mdist,status]]
columns = ('Center Lon/Lat','Area','Perimeter','Mean Width','Status')
rows = ['TODOpolyname']
cwid = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
the_table = tab.table(cellText=stats,colWidths=cwid,rowLabels=rows,colLabels=columns,loc='center')
table_props = the_table.properties()
table_cells = table_props['child_artists']
for cell in table_cells: cell.set_height(0.5)
plt.show()

return
```

EDIT2: Eventually (un)solved plotting text instead of table. Good enough.

Comment: If you do a lot of this kind of thing, you may want to consider exporting your data to shapefile (via eg, networkx) and creating your plots in QGIS.  The QGIS print composer really puts matplotlib to shame when it comes to managing multiple maps and tables.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not a good programmer (as you can see from the shameful script) and I'm running out of time. Learning QGIS now and transferring everything would take too much time. For the future though it's a great tool. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the table's fontsize with matplotlib.pyplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514005/how-to-change-the-tables-fontsize-with-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue in changing the fontsize. Try the following

```
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(5.5)
```

Worked for me.

Comment: get this error when trying this solution: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_fontsize'`

Comment: If you get that error, but don't get the error on `the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)` you probably did something like `the_table = the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)`, as that indeed would set `the_table` to None. Otherwise it makes no sense the second line would raise the error on `NoneType`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table), `table` has a kwarg called `fontsize`, a float value for the size in points.

In your example from above, for a fontsize of 5 points you would use:

```
    the_table =tab.table(cellText=stats,colWidths=cwid,rowLabels=rows,colLabels=columns,loc='center',fontsize=5)
```

If you require greater control, you can pass a [`FontManager`](http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties) instance to the `cell.set_text_props()` method as described in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/font_table_ttf.html?highlight=table%20cell).  That would enable you to set the family, spacing, style etc, in addition to the size.

EDIT: Playing around with Matplotlib's [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/font_table_ttf.html?highlight=table%20cell), it seems that just passing `fontsize` to the table has no effect.  However, importing

```
    from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
```

and then looping through the cells and running

```
    cell.set_text_props(fontproperties=FontProperties(size = 5))
```

does have the desired effect.  It is unclear why the documented kwarg `fontsize` does not work in this (or apparently in your) case.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: @GDino both methods? Are you using `pyplot.table` or `ax.add_table` ?  Could you provide a MWE with imports and everything?

Comment: Looked the edited answer:     
for key, cell in the_table.get_celld().items():
      row, col = key
      if row > 0 and col > 0:
        cell.set_text_props(fontproperties=FontProperties(size=50))
still not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GDino Does iterating through the cells canonically as `for key, cell in tab.get_celld().items():` make any difference?

Comment: Just did, same result. :(

Comment: At this point, I would only suggest that you try and move the table plot to a separate figure, see if you can determine the source of the problem and try and recombine it and debug.  Or just generate it separately and combine it downstream.