# Changing font size in a Table with matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've searched for solutions and I can't seem to find a way to fix my problem. I have 4 graphs and I'm wanting to put a table into each of the graphs. From the screenshot. Top left graph is almost what I want but it's not legible to read. Is there a way to make the font larger? Like almost as large as the bottom left graph's table. My code below too

[image: Picture 4 graphs]

```
import os, math, time
import matplotlib.animation as animation     
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipython_genutils.py3compat import xrange

fig = plt.figure()
fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
print(fig_size)
fig_size[0] =12
fig_size[1] =12
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
print(fig_size)

fig.patch.set_facecolor('gray')
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((12,2), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((12,2), (0,1), rowspan=6, colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((12,2), (8,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((12,2), (8,1), rowspan=4, colspan=1)

ax1.text(12,3.4,'Table Title',size = 20)
ax1.table(cellText=Table,rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns,loc='center right',colWidths = [0.1]*3) #adds table to graph
#the lines commented out below are things I tried.
atable2 = ax2.table(cellText=Table2,rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns,loc='center right', colWidths = [0.1]*3, fontsize = 24) #, bbox=[0.0,-.58,1,.38]
#atable2.set_fontsize(100)
#atable2.auto_set_font_size(True)
#plt.text(12,3.4,'Table Title',size = 20)
atable2.scale(1, 2)

ax3.table(cellText=Table3,rowLabels=rows, colLabels=columns,loc='bottom', bbox=[0.0,-.85,1,.55]) #.28
```

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514005/how-to-change-the-tables-fontsize-with-matplotlib-pyplot). If the solution from that quesiton does not work you need to be specific about in how far it does not work and add a [mcve] (here the code from the question does not run).