# Changing fontsize for Matplotlib table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, font-size

I have created a table from a dataframe using matplotlib's table feature. However, even when I change the fontsize, the font appears the same and I am unsure why. I even tried expanding or reducing the figsize in addition, but this did nothing. How do I change the cell text size? Thanks!

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, bbox=[0,0,1,1], fontsize = 12)
```

Comment: view this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514005/how-to-change-the-tables-fontsize-with-matplotlib-pyplot) it will answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_fontsize()`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
tab = ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, bbox=[0,0,1,1])
tab.set_fontsize(14)
```

Refer [doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/table_api.html#matplotlib.table.Table.set_fontsize) for further instruction.