# How can I increase the size of the table?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-table

I'm trying to display a pandas dataframe as an image, but when I use plt.show(), I got a small picture of the table, inside a big (invisible) subplot, occupying 90% of the generated window.

I used this code:

```
    # ...

    ax = plt.subplot()

    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

    coeficientes_real_2 = coeficientes_real.transpose()

    table(ax, coeficientes_real_2, colWidths=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], loc='center')

    plt.savefig('mytable.png')

    plt.show()

    #...
```

And got this result:

[image: Result]

How can I increase the size of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514005/how-to-change-the-tables-fontsize-with-matplotlib-pyplot) post, you can scale the whole table with

```
tb = table(ax, coeficientes_real_2, colWidths=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], loc='center')
tb.scale(2,2)
```

Or change the column width and font size individually:

```
tb = table(ax, coeficientes_real_2, colWidths=2*[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], loc='center')
tb.set_fontsize(24)
```