# Rendering a Pandas series as a table

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Is there any way to plot a Pandas series as a **table**? (two columns, one for the indices, and one for values). I want to save the table as a **png** file (i.e. an image)

I went through the [examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) but didn't see anything that outputs a series as a table.

Comment: See the answer at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194482/custom-matplotlib-plot-chess-board-like-table-with-colored-cells

Comment: There is also `plt.table` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524401/how-can-i-place-a-table-on-a-plot-in-matplotlib