# Format a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, pie-chart

```
    MachineName EventLogs
0   P79         Yes
1   P14         Yes
2   P1          No
3   P93         No
```

I count the number of logs in a dataframe using the below statement:

```
df1 = pd.value_counts(df['Logs'].values, sort=False)
```

and when I print `df1`, the output is like below:

```
Yes  2
No   2
dtype: int64
```

I cannot create a pie chart using the result as I need to specify the column names while creating pie chart.

Something like

```
%%chart pie --fields Value,Count --data df1
```

Not sure on how to add the column names to `df1`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), because you have `Series`:

```
df1 = pd.value_counts(df['Logs'].values, sort=False).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['value','count']
```

With sample:

```
df1 = pd.value_counts(df['EventLogs'].values, sort=False).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['value','count']
print (df1)
  value  count
0    No      2
1   Yes      2
```

Or you can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df.EventLogs.value_counts().reset_index(name='Count').rename(columns={'index':'Value'})
print (df1)
  Value  Count
0   Yes      2
1    No      2
```

With `sort=False`:

```
df1 = df.EventLogs.value_counts(sort=False)
                  .reset_index(name='Count')
                  .rename(columns={'index': 'Value'})
print (df1)
  Value  Count
0    No      2
1   Yes      2
```

Another solution is [`Series.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html) - see [visualization in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#pie-plot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.EventLogs.value_counts(sort=False).plot.pie()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Can we place pie chart and a table side by side in a notebook? 

For example, I have a pie chart using "%%chart pie --fields value,count --data df2"  and a table using "%%chart table --fields MachineName --data df_result2" But instead of placing pie chart and table separately, I need to have it side by side. Is there an option for this in IPython?

Comment: Hard question for me, because I never use `IPython` this way, but try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524401/how-can-i-place-a-table-on-a-plot-in-matplotlib). I know in `pandas` if use only `plot` - [tables wih graph](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-tables)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're using to make your pie charts, but pandas has some perfectly reasonable plotting capabilities (through matplotlib).

`df1.plot(kind='pie')`